# How do I use types provided by third party library? (Typescript, Element-UI)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, element-ui

I am fairly new to Typescript and not quite sure how can I take advantage od types that are already provided for out of the box. In my case - in Element UI (element.eleme.io).

I am using Vue 2 with class component syntax, Nuxt.js, ElementUI.

There is types folder in node_modules which contains types that I am interested in, but how do I "apply" them to variables and elements of my code? I understand that the types are installed in my */plugins/element-ui.js* via `Vue.use(Element)`, correct?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Element from 'element-ui'
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en'

Vue.use(Element, { locale })
```

For example below I have a component with `date-picker`. I want this date-picker to follow type structure provided in `element-ui.d.ts`. Also there is attribute called `picker-options`, which also has some types already provided. See below.

Example component:
*components/orders/OrderFilterBar.vue*

```html
<template>
  <el-container class="container-filter__row">
    <el-date-picker
      v-model="dateRange"
      class="container-filter__date"
      type="daterange"
      start-placeholder="Start Date"
      end-placeholder="End Date"
      :picker-options="pickerOptions"
      format="yyyy-MM-dd"
      value-format="yyyy-MM-dd"
      @change="queryDatabaseAsync"
    />
  </el-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { dateFilterPickerOptions } from '@/components/options/datePickerOptions'
import OrderServiceAPI from '~/services/OrderServiceAPI'
import { ProviderState } from '~/types/store/providers.types'

@Component
export default class OrderFilterBar extends Vue {
  /* Props */
  /* State */
  providersState = this.$store.state.dashboard as ProviderState

  /* Data */
  searchQuery: string = ''
  paid: boolean = true
  unpaid: boolean = false
  otherFilter: boolean = false
  dateRange: string[] = []

  pickerOptions = dateFilterPickerOptions

  /* Hooks */
  /* Methods */
  async queryDatabaseAsync(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const resp = await OrderServiceAPI.getFilteredOrders(this.$axios, {
        searchQuery: this.searchQuery,
        paid: this.paid,
        unpaid: this.unpaid,
        dateStart: this.dateRange[0],
        dateEnd: this.dateRange[1],
        providerID: null,
      })
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error('error, ', error.response)
    }
  }

  /* Computed */
  get currentProviderId(): number {
    return this.providersState.currentProvider.id
  }
  /* Watchers */
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

Example types:
*node_modules/element-ui/types/element-ui.d.ts*

```
import Vue, { PluginObject } from 'vue'
import { ElementUIComponent, ElementUIComponentSize, ElementUIHorizontalAlignment } from './component'

import { ElAlert } from './alert'
import { ElAside } from './aside'
import { ElAutocomplete } from './autocomplete'
import { ElBadge } from './badge'
import { ElBreadcrumb } from './breadcrumb'
import { ElBreadcrumbItem } from './breadcrumb-item'
import { ElButton } from './button'
import { ElButtonGroup } from './button-group'
import { ElCard } from './card'
import { ElCarousel } from './carousel'
import { ElCarouselItem } from './carousel-item'
import { ElCascader } from './cascader'
import { ElCheckbox } from './checkbox'
import { ElCheckboxButton } from './checkbox-button'
import { ElCheckboxGroup } from './checkbox-group'
import { ElCol } from './col'
import { ElCollapse } from './collapse'
import { ElCollapseItem } from './collapse-item'
import { ElColorPicker } from './color-picker'
import { ElContainer } from './container'
import { ElDatePicker } from './date-picker'
import { ElDialog } from './dialog'
import { ElDropdown } from './dropdown'
import { ElDropdownItem } from './dropdown-item'
import { ElDropdownMenu } from './dropdown-menu'
import { ElFooter } from './footer'
import { ElForm } from './form'
import { ElFormItem } from './form-item'
import { ElHeader } from './header'
import { ElInput } from './input'
import { ElInputNumber } from './input-number'
import { ElLoading } from './loading'
import { ElMain } from './main'
import { ElMenu } from './menu'
import { ElMenuItem } from './menu-item'
import { ElMenuItemGroup } from './menu-item-group'
import { ElMessage } from './message'
import { ElMessageBox } from './message-box'
import { ElNotification } from './notification'
import { ElOption } from './option'
import { ElOptionGroup } from './option-group'
import { ElPagination } from './pagination'
import { ElPopover } from './popover'
import { ElProgress } from './progress'
import { ElRate } from './rate'
import { ElRadio } from './radio'
import { ElRadioButton } from './radio-button'
import { ElRadioGroup } from './radio-group'
import { ElRow } from './row'
import { ElSelect } from './select'
import { ElSlider } from './slider'
import { ElStep } from './step'
import { ElSteps } from './steps'
import { ElSubmenu } from './submenu'
import { ElSwitch } from './switch'
import { ElTable } from './table'
import { ElTableColumn } from './table-column'
import { ElTag } from './tag'
import { ElTabs } from './tabs'
import { ElTabPane } from './tab-pane'
import { ElTimeline } from './timeline'
import { ElTimelineItem } from './timeline-item'
import { ElTimePicker } from './time-picker'
import { ElTimeSelect } from './time-select'
import { ElTooltip } from './tooltip'
import { ElTransfer } from './transfer'
import { ElTree, TreeData } from './tree'
import { ElUpload } from './upload'
import { ElLink } from './link'
import { ElDivider } from './divider'
import { ElIcon } from './icon'
import { ElCalendar } from './calendar'
import { ElImage } from './image'
import { ElBacktop } from './backtop'
import { ElInfiniteScroll } from './infinite-scroll'
import { ElPageHeader } from './page-header'
import { ElAvatar } from './avatar'
import { ElDrawer } from './drawer'
import { ElPopconfirm } from './popconfirm'
import { ElSkeleton } from './skeleton'
import { ElSkeletonItem } from './skeleton-item'
import { ElCascaderPanel } from './cascader-panel'
import { ElEmpty } from './empty'
import { ElSpinner } from './spinner'

export interface InstallationOptions {
  locale: any,
  i18n: any,
  size: string
}

/** The version of element-ui */
export const version: string

/**
 * Install all element-ui components into Vue.
 * Please do not invoke this method directly.
 * Call `Vue.use(ElementUI)` to install.
 */
export function install (vue: typeof Vue, options: InstallationOptions): void

/** ElementUI component common definition */
export type Component = ElementUIComponent

/** Component size definition for button, input, etc */
export type ComponentSize = ElementUIComponentSize

/** Horizontal alignment */
export type HorizontalAlignment = ElementUIHorizontalAlignment

/** Show animation while loading data */
export const Loading: ElLoading

/** Used to show feedback after an activity. The difference with Notification is that the latter is often used to show a system level passive notification. */
export const Message: ElMessage

/** A set of modal boxes simulating system message box, mainly for message prompt, success tips, error messages and query information */
export const MessageBox: ElMessageBox

/** Displays a global notification message at the upper right corner of the page */
export const Notification: ElNotification

// TS cannot merge imported class with namespace, so declare subclasses instead

/** Alert Component */
export class Alert extends ElAlert {}

/** Aside Component */
export class Aside extends ElAside {}

/** Autocomplete Component */
export class Autocomplete extends ElAutocomplete {}

/** Bagde Component */
export class Badge extends ElBadge {}

/** Breadcrumb Component */
export class Breadcrumb extends ElBreadcrumb {}

/** Breadcrumb Item Component */
export class BreadcrumbItem extends ElBreadcrumbItem {}

/** Button Component */
export class Button extends ElButton {}

/** Button Group Component */
export class ButtonGroup extends ElButtonGroup {}

/** Card Component */
export class Card extends ElCard {}

/** Cascader Component */
export class Cascader extends ElCascader {}

/** Carousel Component */
export class Carousel extends ElCarousel {}

/** Carousel Item Component */
export class CarouselItem extends ElCarouselItem {}

/** Checkbox Component */
export class Checkbox extends ElCheckbox {}

/** Checkbox Button Component */
export class CheckboxButton extends ElCheckboxButton {}

/** Checkbox Group Component */
export class CheckboxGroup extends ElCheckboxGroup {}

/** Colunm Layout Component */
export class Col extends ElCol {}

/** Collapse Component */
export class Collapse extends ElCollapse {}

/** Collapse Item Component */
export class CollapseItem extends ElCollapseItem {}

/** Color Picker Component */
export class ColorPicker extends ElColorPicker {}

/** Container Component */
export class Container extends ElContainer {}

/** Date Picker Component */
export class DatePicker extends ElDatePicker {}

/** Dialog Component */
export class Dialog extends ElDialog {}

/** Dropdown Component */
export class Dropdown extends ElDropdown {}

/** Dropdown Item Component */
export class DropdownItem extends ElDropdownItem {}

/** Dropdown Menu Component */
export class DropdownMenu extends ElDropdownMenu {}

/** Footer Component */
export class Footer extends ElFooter {}

/** Form Component */
export class Form extends ElForm {}

/** Form Item Component */
export class FormItem extends ElFormItem {}

/** Header Component */
export class Header extends ElHeader {}

/** Input Component */
export class Input extends ElInput {}

/** Input Number Component */
export class InputNumber extends ElInputNumber {}

/** Main Component */
export class Main extends ElMain {}

/** Menu that provides navigation for your website */
export class Menu extends ElMenu {}

/** Menu Item Component */
export class MenuItem extends ElMenuItem {}

/** Menu Item Group Component */
export class MenuItemGroup extends ElMenuItemGroup {}

/** Dropdown Select Option Component */
export class Option extends ElOption {}

/** Dropdown Select Option Group Component */
export class OptionGroup extends ElOptionGroup {}

/** Pagination Component */
export class Pagination extends ElPagination {}

/** Popover Component */
export class Popover extends ElPopover {}

/** Progress Component */
export class Progress extends ElProgress {}

/** Rate Component */
export class Rate extends ElRate {}

/** Radio Component */
export class Radio extends ElRadio {}

/** Radio Button Component */
export class RadioButton extends ElRadioButton {}

/** Radio Group Component */
export class RadioGroup extends ElRadioGroup {}

/** Row Layout Component */
export class Row extends ElRow {}

/** Dropdown Select Component */
export class Select extends ElSelect {}

/** Slider Component */
export class Slider extends ElSlider {}

/** Step Component */
export class Step extends ElStep {}

/** Steps Component */
export class Steps extends ElSteps {}

/** Submenu Component */
export class Submenu extends ElSubmenu {}

/** Switch Component */
export class Switch extends ElSwitch {}

/** Table Component */
export class Table extends ElTable {}

/** Table Column Component */
export class TableColumn extends ElTableColumn {}

/** Tabs Component */
export class Tabs extends ElTabs {}

/** Tab Pane Component */
export class TabPane extends ElTabPane {}

/** Tag Component */
export class Tag extends ElTag {}

/** Timeline Component */
export class Timeline extends ElTimeline {}

/** Timeline Item Component */
export class TimelineItem extends ElTimelineItem {}

/** TimePicker Component */
export class TimePicker extends ElTimePicker {}

/** TimeSelect Component */
export class TimeSelect extends ElTimeSelect {}

/** Tooltip Component */
export class Tooltip extends ElTooltip {}

/** Transfer Component */
export class Transfer extends ElTransfer {}

/** Tree Component */
export class Tree<K = any, D = TreeData> extends ElTree<K, D> {}

/** Upload Component */
export class Upload extends ElUpload {}

/** Divider Component */
export class Divider extends ElDivider {}

/** Link Component */
export class Link extends ElLink {}

/** Image Component */
export class Image extends ElImage {}

/** Icon Component */
export class Icon extends ElIcon {}

/** Calendar Component */
export class Calendar extends ElCalendar {}

/** Backtop Component */
export class Backtop extends ElBacktop {}

/** InfiniteScroll Directive */
export const InfiniteScroll: PluginObject<ElInfiniteScroll>;

/** PageHeader Component */
export class PageHeader extends ElPageHeader {}

/** Avatar Component */
export class Avatar extends ElAvatar {}

/** Drawer Component */
export class Drawer extends ElDrawer {}

/** Popconfirm Component */
export class Popconfirm extends ElPopconfirm {}

/** Skeleton Component */
export class Skeleton extends ElSkeleton {}

/** Skeleton Item Component */
export class SkeletonItem extends ElSkeletonItem {}

/** CascaderPanel Component */
export class CascaderPanel extends ElCascaderPanel {}

/** Empty Component */
export class Empty extends ElEmpty {}

/** Spinner Component */
export class Spinner extends ElSpinner {}
```

Picker-options
*components/options/datePickerOptions.ts*

```
import DatePickerOptions from 'element-ui'

export const dateFilterPickerOptions: DatePickerOptions = { // ERROR in DatePickerOptions saying: Cannot use namespace 'DatePickerOptions' as a type.ts(2709)
  disabledDate(time: { getTime: () => number }) {
    return time.getTime() > Date.now()
  },
  shortcuts: [
    {
      text: 'Today',
      onClick(picker: {
        $emit: (arg0: string, arg1: Date) => void
      }) {
        picker.$emit('pick', new Date())
      },
    },
    {
      text: 'Yesterday',
      onClick(picker: { $emit: (arg0: string, arg1: Date) => void }): void {
        const yesterday = new Date()
        yesterday.setTime(yesterday.getTime() - 3600 * 1000 * 24)
        picker.$emit('pick', yesterday)
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Lastly, my index.d.ts:

```
import Vue, { ComponentOptions } from 'vue';
import { VueClass } from './declarations';
export { createDecorator, VueDecorator, mixins } from './util';
declare function Component<V extends Vue>(options: ComponentOptions<V> & ThisType<V>): <VC extends VueClass<V>>(target: VC) => VC;
declare namespace Component {
    var registerHooks: (keys: string[]) => void;
}
declare function Component<VC extends VueClass<Vue>>(target: VC): VC;
declare namespace Component {
    var registerHooks: (keys: string[]) => void;
}
export default Component;
```

My question is: how do I make my `date-picker` to follow the structure described in types? It is confusing for me as the `date-picker` is declared in `template`, which is just a regular `<tag>` and obviously I need to assign types in Javascript.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the date picker, the `element-ui` index [exports only the class definition of `ElDatePicker`](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/1f4adb7c084f83e122ffbfe28c330cab067e5a16/types/element-ui.d.ts#L24).

But `DatePickerOptions` is available as a [named export from `element-ui/types/date-picker`](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/1f4adb7/types/date-picker.d.ts#L50):

```js
import { DatePickerOptions } from 'element-ui/types/date-picker'
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-element-ui-date-picker-ts?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Foptions%2FdatePickerOptions.ts)